# How to make [Enter] only run a handler?

Tags: javascript, html, enter

I'm studying through Head First HTML5. They have a tutorial in the book on how to create a very basic playlist in JavaScript. On click of a button entered text is added to a list. I thought, "I would prefer to just hit the enter key." So, I tried taking it a step further to make the keypress run the appropriate function.

It almost seems like the [Enter] key adds the new text to the list, but then refreshes the page and the entire list, deleting any entered text! I checked to see if the same thing happened with any of the other keys and they all worked fine, so this is only something that happens with the [Enter] key.

```js
window.onload = init;

function feedTheList() {
    var textInput, songName, li, ul;

    textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");
    songName = textInput.value;
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = songName;
    if (!songName) {
        alert("There is no new song name.")
    }
    else {
        ul = document.getElementById("playlist");
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

function init() {
    var button, textBox;

    window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            feedTheList();
        }
    });

    button = document.getElementById("addButton");
    button.onclick = feedTheList;
}
```

Why is the [Enter] key refreshing the page? How do I prevent it from refreshing the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a form field (input or textarea) the [enter] key is mapped to 'submit' the form. You need to [prevent the default action behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) using `event.preventDefault()`:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        feedTheList();
    }
});
```